# How many tests I can make before I need Bonferroni correction?

Tags: bonferroni

I wanna make t-test for effect of gender, another t-test for effect of age, one-way ANOVA for effect of education and MIXED ANOVA (3x8) for another effect? Should I use Bonferroni corection? All is on same dependent variable.

Comment: You might want to read this Q&A http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120362/whats-wrong-with-bonferroni-adjustments for some alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

The key point about the multiple testing problem is that every time you have a p-value you have to pay -- like rolling the dice in a casino.  A table of p-values needs to be adjusted by the number of tests.  Bonferroni is very conservative (i.e., will really lower the adjusted p-values) so you may want to invoke the false discovery rate (FDR) instead -- look up the 1995 paper by Benjamini & Hochberg.  But yes, for 2-way and multiway ANOVA, most labs apply a Bonferroni correction.

Comment: There is also bootstrap and permutation p-value adjustment methods.  This is covered in the book by Westfall and Young.  "Resampling-Based Multiple Testing Examples and Methods for p-value Adjustment"  Peter H. Westfall and S. Stanley Young, Wiley 1993.

Comment: Here is a URL for it.  www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471557617.html

Comment: The Westfall & Young procedure is also a good option.

Comment: I noticed that Peter Westfall is also a member on CV.  The advantage of the bootstrap approach is that it is not nearly as conservative as Bonferroni.  I am pretty sure it deals with family-wise error rate and not False Discovery Rate.